# C# Reflection : Type cast method return value in specific type of object list

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have following assemble which contains following data

`demo.dll`

**Class 1**

```
namespace demo

public class Data
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

**Class 2**

```
namespace demo

public class Utility
{
   private List<Data> items;

   public Utility()
   {
      items = new List<Data>();
      items.add(new Data(){ FirstName = "Abc" });
   }

   public List<Data> GetItems()
   {
       return items;
   }
}
```

Now I want to load above demo.dll assemble using runtime and call `GetItem()` method.

For that I can write following code

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ,"demo.dll"));

Type Utility= assembly.GetType("demo.Utility");
Type Data= assembly.GetType("demo.Data");

MethodInfo GetItems = Utility.GetMethod("GetItems");

object utility = Activator.CreateInstance(Utility);

object returnValue = GetItems.Invoke(utility, null);
```

Now I want to type cast above `returnValue` in List of type Data and access the `FirstName` property.

How can I achieve this using reflection?

Comment: *Now I want to type cast above 'returnValue'* By cast you mean a reference conversion that gives you a `List<Data>` reference? You can’t do that, that’s only useful/usable if you know the type at compile time something you obviously don’t. You have a runtime object with no static type information (except that its an `object`). You either access all properties/methods via reflection or you use `dynamic`. Both essentially amount to the same thing: late or runtime binding and zero type safety at compile time, but you *are* already in that spot so it’s not that it’s gettinh worse.

Comment: @InBetween Yes as you said, other than how can I use information inside the 'returnValue' ?? for example I want to print firstname from the all objects inside the list.

Comment: @InBetween Thank you for giving me your precious time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that everything you wrote works then

```
object returnValue = GetItems.Invoke(utility, null);
```

`returnValue` is actually a `List<Data>`, but you can't cast it, because at compile time the compiler doesn't have the type information of the `Data` class. But since a `List<T>` implements `IList` you can cast to that and iterate over its items (`IEnumerable<object>` should work too).

Then you can use reflection again to access the `FirstName` property:

```
var returnValue = (IList)GetItems.Invoke(utility, null);

foreach (var item in returnValue)
{
    var type = item.GetType();
    var property = type.GetProperty("FirstName");
    var firstName = property.GetValue(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is exactly which I need